# jOOQ: Commenting arbitrary parts of generated SQL

Tags: sql, kotlin, jooq

I'd like to add comments to aid debugging large, generated SQL statements

The below works for fields, but is there a more generic form that I can use to also attach comments to joins, order-by/group-bys, etc?

```
fun org.jooq.Field<*>.comment(comment: String) = DSL.field("/* $comment */ {0}", this.dataType, this)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Existing feature requests

There have been some feature requests on the issue tracker for related features, including:

- [#2541](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2541) Add support for inserting custom clauses in a Select statement through .sql(String)

  This feature request was rejected as it was focused only on the DSL API, not generically on all `QueryPart` types that are part of an arbitrary expression tree.
- [#13049](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13049) Add new API to maintain comments and other whitespace in the expression tree

  This feature is described as being useful mainly for [parsing](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/) and [SQL dialect translation purposes](https://www.jooq.org/translate/), but obviously, such a feature
  would be useful to your use-case as well.

Doing this is a big project in jOOQ (currently version 3.17), as jOOQ maintains only the significant parts of a SQL expression tree. Comments and whitespace tend to be insignificant in SQL. Given that they can appear at any possible location, including e.g. between keywords that have no representation in the jOOQ API, it will be difficult to implement [#13049](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13049) thoroughly. For example, jOOQ has a `groupBy()` method, but that's 2 keywords in SQL:

```sql
GROUP BY
```

and users might want to put a comment in between them:

```sql
GROUP /* comment */ BY
```

The [SQL dialect translation](https://www.jooq.org/translate/) use-case is a strong one in favour of this feature, at least to be implemented to some extent, so this might ship in a not too distant future

#### Workarounds as of jOOQ 3.17

The 2 main ways to annotate your SQL with comments are currently:

- [Plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). You found a solution for `Field`, but you can wrap most popular `QueryPart` types in a template, including `Table` (i.e. joins) and others. It's ugly, but it works.
- [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/) SPI allows you to patch your generated SQL globally with a single `Configuration`, rather than having to think about this on a per query basis.